# App to app authentication laravel WordPress

Tags: php, laravel-5, restful-authentication

I have an API built on Laravel 5 and several web laravel apps and wordpress blogs that talk to that API. I need a way to authenticate the apps, as there are no user accounts involved in my applications. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you basically want to only your blogs to communicate with your app and ignore other traffic? I would either create a secret and attach it to each request your blogs make, then check it in the app (preffered) or check the referrer of each request to your app and allow only the ones coming from your blogs.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any security concerns with using an app secret? How can I make sure my app secret doesn't get sniffed?

Comment: you should make sure all calls are made thru your blogs and not not directly to the app, especially ajax calls